# Gurobi in docker container problem generating unique host ID for this machine

Tags: docker, gurobi

I am trying to install Gurobi on my docker container, but when I run `grbgetkey` I get this message.

`info  : grbgetkey version 8.1.1, build v8.1.1rc0`

`error : Problem generating unique host ID for this machine.`

I haven't generated a license file yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complicated to license commercial software inside a Docker container, so we created this error intentionally. Please contact [Gurobi support directly](https://support.gurobi.com) for license options inside Docker.